# about $.get() callback function argument

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I use Ajax for asynchronous communication, I may use the $.get() method, which is often used in callback functions as follows:

```
$.get('http://example.com', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

I just wonder about 'result' parameter.
Where did that parameter that says 'result' come from? 
It doesn't matter if I put any name in it, so I can't put a second or third argument in that function? If it can be put in, how should it be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function, you can give the parameters any name you like (so long as they are valid identifiers):

```
function foo(a, b, c) { }
```

When the function is called, the arguments are passed to those parameters in order:

```
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

It is exactly the same for:

> ```
> function(result) {
>   console.log(result);
> }
> ```

The only difference is that the function is called by code **written by someone else** (which is part of the jQuery library).

---

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) tells you what arguments are passed:

> **success**
>  Type: Function( PlainObject `data`, String `textStatus`, jqXHR `jqXHR` )
>  A callback function that is executed
>   if the request succeeds. Required if dataType is provided, but you can
>   use null or jQuery.noop as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

The callback will be invoked when the query is succeeded, then jQuery will pass the data to the first argument, and the following arguments is textStatus and jqXHR. For more you can check the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/